# iframe content returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a website preview in an iframe.

```
<iframe style="width:100%;height:850px;" id="myframe" 
src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

There is an input field on that website with the id and name of 'firstField'. However, it returns undefined when I do this:

```
alert($('myframe').contents().find('#firstField').val());
```

Is there something I can doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying the wrong selector. The correct one to select the iframe is `$("#myframe")`.

Change the code to this, and retry:

```
alert($('#myframe').contents().find('#firstField').val());
```

To learn more about the ID selector, refer [this guide](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).